# How references are passed while executing methods?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, heap-memory, stack-memory

Here is my democlass where i am trying to implement the switching mechanism and trying to figure out how the object references are passed while executing methods:
Here is my main demo class:

```
package referenceOrValue;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DemoFoo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> demoArray = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayList.add("a");
    arrayList.add("b");
    arrayList.add("c");
    demoArray.add("d");
    demoArray.add("e");
    demoArray.add("f");


    System.out.println("The arraylist  is " + arrayList);
    System.out.println("The demo array is " + demoArray);
    Foo foo = new Foo();    


    //foo.setNull(arrayList);
    foo.switching(arrayList, demoArray);
    System.out.println("The arraylist  after switch " + arrayList);
     System.out.println("The demo array after switch " + demoArray);




}

}
```

now there is a foo class like this whose sole function is to swap the values in the arraylist:

```
package referenceOrValue;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo {

public void switching (ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<String> b){

    ArrayList<String> temp=null;
temp=a;
a=b;
b=temp;
System.out.println("The arraylist  inside switch " + a);
System.out.println("The demo array inside switch " + b);
}
}
```

now the main problem is the output:-(

```
The arraylist  is [a, b, c]
The demo array is [d, e, f]
The arraylist  inside switch [d, e, f]
The demo array inside switch [a, b, c]
The arraylist  after switch [a, b, c]
The demo array after switch [d, e, f]
```

According to my knowledge the this switching should have executed properly but result is bit surprising for me as inside the switching method i am not creating new objects as:

```
a= new ArrayList<>();
```

so "a" is still referring to the [a,b,c] and during the switching operation values are changed in the method as shown in output, but the main class has unchanged object.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly after passing in the array lists into the method ...

1. ... the parameter *a* is referencing the same array list as the variable *arrayList* from main method
2. ... the parameter *b* is referencing the same array list as the variable *demoArray* from main method.

But before printing out the contents you switch the references! So at the point where you print the contents ...

1. ... the parameter *a* is referencing the same array list as the variable *demoArray* from main method
2. ... the parameter *b* is referencing the same array list as the variable *arrayList* from main method.

And as Java always passes *by value*, the variables (which just hold references) in the main method are untouched. So they print out the same content as before.